# Swinging Pendulum ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is a pendulum with the ability to swing freely

I have a system of first order differential equations of the following form:

$\dfrac {d\theta} {dt}$=$\omega$

$\dfrac {d\omega} {dt}$=$-\dfrac glsin\theta-\dfrac{r(w)} {lm}$

we also know that $r(0)=0$ and $r'(0)>0$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the string and the vertical position and $\theta=0$ is the pendulums natural resting position, $l$ is the length of the string, $m$ is the mass of the object at the end of the string

I am trying to find the equilibrium points of the ODE system above and to describe what position of the pendulum they correspond to.

I imagine that to find the equilibrium points you set both equations equal to 0 and solve. And just from an intuitive standpoint I would guess that the equilibrium points are the exact moment when the pendulum reaches it's max peak height through each swing before it starts to fall again but I am having trouble getting that from the equations

Comment: What is $r$? Is that intended to be a function of $\omega$ or $r$ times $\omega$. In either case what does it physically represent? It can't be the length of the pendulum because that is $l$.

Comment: r(w) models the frictional force where w is the angular velocity

Comment: Undestood, then we know that this is $0$ if $\omega=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equilibrium position would correspond to the location for which your angular acceleration is zero *and* the angular velocity is zero. The angular velocity being zero allows $\theta$ to remain constant. The angular acceleration being zero allows $\omega$ to stay zero.

So we know $\omega=0$ and $\frac{d \omega}{dt}=0$ which makes the second equation,

$$ 0=-\frac{g}{l} \sin(\theta) -\frac{r(0)}{ml}$$

Since $r(\omega)$ is the frictional force the pendulum experiences we know this must be $0$ when $\omega=0$ (friction doesn't cause motion it impedes it). This gives the equation,

$$ 0 = -\frac{g}{l} \sin(\theta)  \quad \Rightarrow \quad \theta=0,\pi$$

Therefore the equilibrium position is at the bottom of the swing. The object will stay in that equilibrium provided that its velocity is zero.

There is also an equilibrium at $180^\circ$ from the bottom (i.e, the top), but this is only physically realizable if the pendulum is a rigid rod. A ball on a string couldn't stay there in equilibrium.

Comment: could the ball not stay there for a split second? also see my edits to the problem above

Comment: It certainly could but equilibrium implies that the force is $0$. This can't be the case with a real pendulum supported by a string because the string won't be able to provide a force against gravity. A rigid rod could support a force along its axis allowing us to counter gravity and therefore be in actual equilibrium.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint 1:** You are on the right track for the equilibrium points (EPs).

We have the EPs when we simultaneously set each equation to $0$ and get the critical points:

$$(n \pi, 0)$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which of course includes the point $(0,0)$.

Now, what is the $\pi$ term telling you?

**Hint 2:**

Linearize around those critical points and analyze the resulting system.

**Hint 3:**

Draw a phase portrait and analyze the behaviors.

Comment: I like *this* answer! $+^+$

Comment: Hello! I thought maybe you were "breaking" from MSE! Naps are good!! (and Yes, slow indeed.)